# Point Cloud Registration with low (and undiscernible) features

Tags: registration, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

1. The Objective

The scanned object is composed of two main parts: a conical structure, without a basis; and, in the middle of the first part, a cylindrical structure. We will call the first part as “body” and the second as “pipe”. The diameter from the pipe is known (or very accurately estimated). The distance between the body’s extreme and the pipe’s center is unknown. A state-of-the-art structured light laser scanner is assembled on a circular trajectory around the target object. The scanner pose and movement angle between “takes” are barely known.

Based on a circular trajectory, we have N captures from the target. From this, we could infer the movement angle between each take is equal then 360/N. After the captures, we need to take these N point clouds and merge in a unique (and complete) point cloud, which represents the complete object. Something [like this tutorial](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/registration_api.php).

[Ilustration of the scanner, target and trajectory.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYRsl.png)

2. What was already tried

In our captures, we have a very uniform object. This characteristic faced us as a problem because the relevant points detected in the point cloud are very similar to a lot of other points, in different positions on the cloud. But only one is the correct correspondence. Because this, we have a lot of false correspondences, which makes the transformation computation fails.

We executed a lot of experiments using the algorithms implemented by PointCloud Library (PCL). Changing parameters on the keypoints detectors (ISS, Random Sampling, Harris, etc.), descriptors (based on colors like SHOTRGB, normals, and/or geometry like FPFH), linear-solving techniques (SVD, MLS, etc.). We can’t achieve a relevant result.

**Has someone faced a problem similar to this?**

**How can I improve my description mode?**

**Can I use another approach made for high-uniform datasets?**

**Any contribution is welcomed.**

Answer (score 0):

If N is large enough (is it something under your control?), Optical Flow should be a good candidate to **find correspondences**.

The feature-based keypoints detectors you mentioned are one approach to find correspondence between points (you find keypoints in both images and then match them using the features).

**OpticalFlow is the map between two images of where each point moved.** So this gives you an alternative way to find point correspondence. This approach assumes the two images are similar enough (=that your N is large enough) leverages this similarity.

This can be better understood by comparison: feature-based approach considers each image separately, and tries to match points individually (in the feature space). OpticalFlow considers both images to find a "smooth" transformation/mapping between them. The feature-based approach is the "standard" one, due to it's much higher robustness and invariance.

In your particular case, it might be possible to use the OpticalFlow approach.

OpenCV has an implementation of [OpticalFlow](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/d6b/group__video__track.html#ga473e4b886d0bcc6b65831eb88ed93323) and offers a [tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/dee/tutorial_optical_flow.html). If we look at the example:

> `calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(old_gray, frame_gray, p0, p1, ...);`

Given two images (old_gray and frame_gray) and a set of points (p0) in the first image (old_gray), it calculates where these points (p1) are in the second image (frame_gray). In other words, the point sets p0 and p1 are a correspondence between the two images. You can try any keypoint detection method to choose your p0 set of points.

Alternatively, you could use [calcOpticalFlowFarneback](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/dee/tutorial_optical_flow.html) to get  dense correspondence.

Additional materiel:
[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_flow), [Short video lesson from Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/robotics-perception/optical-flow-2d-point-correspondences-p4yng).

Comment: I've read about optical flow, but I don't have knowledge enough to implement my own version and can't find a package ready and useful to my problem.
I have a lot of point, its really complicated.

Comment: You wrote "optical flow", i've read "optimal mass"...
How can I use optical flow in this context? Could you provide a example, pleease?

Comment: @Lucas Amparo, I added more explanations to my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Mark, thanks for the answer. This technique are useful for images but my problem uses a point cloud.

Comment: But isn't each capture an "organized" cloud? Does your sensor have color information? If so, then each frame can be regarded as an image.

Comment: The capture wasn't organized. I just have a point cloud with color information. Maybe the sensor give us some information about calibration, but isn't in my hands now...